# Insert an element into matrix through loop in Mathematica

Tags: for-loop, matrix, resize, wolfram-mathematica

I am trying to increase the size of matrix below through for loop but the code gives an error that I have not found a solution until this point. Here is my code,

```
m = 1;
n = 1;
mat2 = Table[0, {m}, {n}];
For[i = 1, i <= n + 1, i++,
    For[j = 1, j <= m + 1, j++,
            mat2[[i, j]] = j
    ];
  ];
mat2 // MatrixForm
```

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

```
In[1]:= m = 2; n = 2; mat2 = Table[i + j, {i, m}, {j, n}];
mat2 = ArrayPad[mat2, {0, 1}];
mat2 // MatrixForm

Out[3]//MatrixForm=
{{2, 3, 0},
 {3, 4, 0},
 {0, 0, 0}}
```

Answer (score 0):

a neat little trick using `SparseArray` ..

```
 mat = SparseArray[Table[1, {5}, {5}]]
```

[image]

```
 mat = SparseArray[Prepend[ArrayRules[mat], {6, 8} -> 9]]
```

note this copies the entire array to a new larger array (as does `ArrayPad` ), so you really don't want to be doing this often for large arrays.

[image]

likewise an "assignment" into an existing position works, but you don't want to do this for performance reasons:

```
 mat = SparseArray[Prepend[ArrayRules[mat], {2, 2} -> 3]]
```

[image]

rather than growing arrays you would be better off to define a sufficiently large `SparseArray` in the first place (there is little/no memory hit for making a huge empty  SparseArray)

```
 mat = SparseArray[Table[1, {5}, {5}], {1000, 1000}];
 mat[[6, 8]] = 9;
 mat[[2, 2]] = 3;
```

(just don't try to print this..)

when done save the non-empty part:

```
 mat=SparseArray[ArrayRules[mat]]
```

[image]